# not working css background property in chrome

Tags: css

I tried the following code:

**CSS:**

```
.bg_left{
        background-image: url(path/image.jpeg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left bottom;
         background-color: #FF0000;
         color:#FFFFFF;
         height:150px;

}
table{width:100%;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 responsive website tutorial</title>

</head>
<body>
<table>
   <tr class="bg_left">
      <td>Helloo
      </td>
      <td>Logout</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But why does it repeat in chrome while it works fine in IE and Firefox?

Comment: try the full url of the image

Comment: how this code works fine in IE and FF with the class name mismatch?

Comment: Sorry Class name is same.

Comment: @VinodVT.. Full url didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.bg_left{
  background-image: url(images/banner1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  height:150px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
   <tr class="bg_left">
      <td>Helloo</td>
      <td>Logout</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The classname is your HTML is `bg_left`. But you use `bg-left` is your CSS file

Comment: Sorry Class name is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .bg_left{
        background-image: url(images/6.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left bottom;

}
<table>
   <tr class="bg_left">
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: class name is missing

Comment: Sorry Class name is same.

Comment: Hi this code my side is working, another way to add height and width than i thing working

Comment: Seems like a different rendering among the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, try moving the class to each of td.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 responsive website tutorial</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bg_left {
            background-image: url('http://s1.wallippo.com/thumbs/300x250/background-black-chaninja-hexican-vista-wave-windows-e18886707bb2610e73c06c8f8574c7c5.jpeg');
            background-position: left bottom;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: #FF0000;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            height: 150px;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="bg_left">
                Helloo
            </td>
            <td class="bg_left">Logout</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to set background in tr. why this not possible?

Comment: If you remove background-position: left bottom;   it will display the same way on all browsers. This is related to differences by the way the browsers renders.